# Method for analysis of sorting algorithm

Tags: python, analysis

I have 4 sorting algorithms (linear, frequency, binary and hash table) for sorting lists of words.

I need to analyse the number of comparisons that each makes, given a list of *n* words and compare them to each other. To do this I will count comparisons performed by each algorithm on lists of varying size.

My approach is to simulate words with integers (which should cut down comparison time and make range generation easier for my testing function). I am currently assuming the average vocabulary of text is 300 words. of wich 20% are repeated with a reasonable frequency, 30% are less common and the remaining 50% are compartively rare.

> **Is this approach fair and logical**? Ie: will it (reasonably) accurately represent a typical list of words as copied from a block of typical text.

The code I am using to simulate a list of words from text is as follows:

```
from random import randint, shuffle

def get_list(size):
    '''return list of psuedo random integers
       in a list of length size, to represent
       a typical block of text'''

    my_list = []

    #percent of words that are typically most common, common, rare
    most_common = 20
    common = 30
    rare = 50
    vocab = 300

    for word in range(0, int(size * (most_common / 100))):
        my_list.append(randint(0, 5))
    for word in range(0, int(size * (common / 100))):
        my_list.append(randint(0, 20))
    for word in range(0, int(size * (rare / 100))):
        my_list.append(randint(0, vocab))

    shuffle(my_list)
    return my_list
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With total number 300, you would not able to see any significant difference in performance. I believe you should probably increase your input number for words more than 5000.

Generally for sorting words, you  may use HashTable as it is more efficient and can save space.

you may also look for "tries" data structure if you have use case of predicative text.

Comment: Thanks +1 for vocab range recommendation, when I get the rep :)